# SIGEP - Serviço não autorizado

Tags: web-service

No ServicoDePostagem.php do php-sigep essas linhas podem ser alteradas de acordo com os códigos recebidos no buscaCliente() ou são códigos que não devem ser alterados?

```
linha 9: const SERVICE_PAC_41068 = 04669;
linha 13: const SERVICE_SEDEX_40096 = 04162;
linha 32: self::SERVICE_PAC_41068 => array('Pac 41068', 124884),
linha 36: self::SERVICE_SEDEX_40096 => array('Sedex 40096', 124849),
```

Comment: @Stavarengo podem me dar uma luz NOVAMENTE? :)

Comment: Você sabe que marcar uma pessoa que não interagiu não adianta de nada, confere?

Comment: Sim. Mas não marquei. Só editei a minha pergunta. Se puder ver as datas, verá que o comentário que marquei a pessoa é do dia 13/12. Confere?